# Check Identity values over multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've the following statement that returns me the current identity values for one database

```sql
;WITH cte
AS
(SELECT
        A.TABLE_CATALOG AS CATALOG
       ,A.TABLE_SCHEMA AS "SCHEMA"
       ,A.TABLE_NAME AS "TABLE"
       ,B.COLUMN_NAME AS "COLUMN"
       ,IDENT_SEED(A.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + A.TABLE_NAME) AS SEED
       ,IDENT_INCR(A.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + A.TABLE_NAME) AS INCREMENT
       ,IDENT_CURRENT(A.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + A.TABLE_NAME) AS CURR_VALUE
       ,b.DATA_TYPE AS TYPE
       ,CASE LOWER(B.DATA_TYPE)
            WHEN 'bigint' THEN IDENT_CURRENT(A.TABLE_NAME) / 9223372036854775807
            WHEN 'int' THEN IDENT_CURRENT(A.TABLE_NAME) / 2147483647
            WHEN 'smallint' THEN IDENT_CURRENT(A.TABLE_NAME) / 32767
            WHEN 'tinyint' THEN IDENT_CURRENT(A.TABLE_NAME) / 255
        END AS [RATIO]
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES A
        ,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns B
    WHERE A.TABLE_CATALOG = B.TABLE_CATALOG
    AND A.TABLE_SCHEMA = B.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND A.TABLE_NAME = B.TABLE_NAME
    AND COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(A.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + A.TABLE_NAME), B.COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(A.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + A.TABLE_NAME), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1
    AND A.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE')
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE RATIO > @threshold
```

| CATALOG | SCHEMA | TABLE | COLUMN | SEED | INCREMENT | CURR_VALUE | TYPE | RATIO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Database1 | dbo | TableName1 | ColumnName1 | 1 | 1 | 1118658505 | int | 0.520916 |
| Database1 | dbo | TableName2 | ColumnName2 | 1 | 1 | 926923907 | int | 0.431633 |

How can I run this (or an equal) statment against all databases on the server so I get a result in one table?

| CATALOG | SCHEMA | TABLE | COLUMN | SEED | INCREMENT | CURR_VALUE | TYPE | RATIO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Database1 | dbo | TableName1 | ColumnName1 | 1 | 1 | 1118658505 | int | 0.520916 |
| Database1 | dbo | TableName2 | ColumnName2 | 1 | 1 | 926923907 | int | 0.431633 |
| Database2 | dbo | TableName3 | ColumnName3 | 1 | 1 | 401894827 | int | 0.187146 |
| Database2 | dbo | TableName4 | ColumnName4 | 1 | 1 | 756925871 | int | 0.352471 |

I've tried to use `USE [<DATABASE_NAME>]` but would need dynamic SQL and would also receive multiple return sets instead of one.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI it's **2023**, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax came out *31 years ago*. It is *long* past time you adopted it by now. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) Also, speaking of bad habits: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: As for the question, you'll need to use dynamic SQL to either iterate through your databases and `INSERT` the data from each into a (temporary) table or build a large `UNION ALL` query that you can then execute.

Comment: What's the point of this question? It matters. Perhaps you're looking for the wrong thing?  You can use the `sys.identity_columns` system table instead of all those JOINs. You can use the undocumented `sp_MSforeachdb` to run the query on every database. You won't get a single result set in every case though. You can use a three-part name to include the database in the query but that *does* require dynamic SQL

Comment: Why are you asking for this? There's a reason it's not already available - typically it's not needed. Identity values have meaning only for their specific tables. Database-wide incrementing values are provided by SEQUENCE objects. If you want to detect changes, capture old data or replicate data you should use the relevant features (change tracking, change data capture, replication)

Comment: Is the `RATIO` column the real reason? Was IDENTITY used in narrow columns like `tinyint` and `smallint`? Why not use a suitable type from the start? Even with a small lookup table `tinyint` can get exhausted after a while as rows are deleted and inserted

Comment: I had a similar need recently and used a PowerShell script to execute a query against many servers/databases and report consolidated results, including server name. The query was identical, with only the server and database in the connection different for each iteration. You might consider than instead of dynamic SQL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I'll stand in as proxy for your ersatz inquisition. Monitoring identity values is a good idea. Of course with perfect forethought one always chooses the best datatype for everything. But sometimes you get it wrong. Isn't it better to have some advanced warning of a potential overrun that is going to take time to fix instead of incurring an outage because you created more widgets than you thought you were going to at design time?

Comment: @BenThul that doesn't help understand what the OP wants, or why `sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ?; select * from sys.identity_columns` isn't enough. The need for *one* result set suggests a report but that's just a guess, based on the columns and expressions. The results could be combined with `INSERT  INTO @someTable EXEC sp_MSforeachdb`. That wouldn't work if the OP wants use this in a view though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - maybe I missed it, but where did they say that `sp_MSforeachdb` wasn't acceptable? Is it possible that OP just didn't know about it?

Comment: They didn't. That's the point. 7 hours after my comments it's unclear what the actual restrictions are. The request for only one result set suggests they want to filter the results.  `sp_MSforeachdb` doesn't allow that. The results can be combined but not filtered the way a view or CTE can be filtered. My answer shows how to do this but I don't know if it's relevant or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query itself can be simplified a lot by querying the [sys.identity_columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-identity-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) system view, which already contains table, column, last value, seed and even *size* information in bytes, in the form of the `max_length` column

For example :

```
select DB_NAME() As DB,
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_ID) as SchemaName,
    object_name(object_id) as TableName,
    name as ColumnName,
    TYPE_NAME(system_type_id) as ColumnType,
    cast(Seed_value as bigint) Seed_Value,
    cast(Increment_value as bigint) as Increment_Value,
    POWER(2.0,max_length*7) as MaxSize,
    cast(last_value as bigint) as Last_value,
    cast(Last_value as bigint)/POWER(2.0,max_length*7) as ratio
from sys.identity_columns;
```

The maximum size is generated by raising 2 to the number of bits. `max_length*7` is used instead of `max_length*8` because the question seems to only count *positive* ID values. Nothing prevents negative ID values though.

`seed_value`, `increment_value` and `last_value` are a `sql_variant` columns that must be cast to a numeric type before they're used in calculations.

This query can be executed against all databases using the undocumented but globally (as in used by everyone,everywhere) `sp_MSForEachDB` stored procedure

```
declare @sql nvarchar(2000)=N'USE ?; 
select DB_NAME() As DB,
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_ID) as SchemaName,
    object_name(object_id) as TableName,
    name as ColumnName,
    TYPE_NAME(system_type_id) as ColumnType,
    cast(Seed_value as bigint) Seed_Value,
    cast(Increment_value as bigint) as Increment_Value,
    POWER(2.0,max_length*7) as MaxSize,
    cast(last_value as bigint) as Last_value,
    cast(Last_value as bigint)/POWER(2.0,max_length*7) as ratio
from sys.identity_columns;'

exec sp_MSForEachDB @sql
```

This produces multiple result sets. These can be inserted into a temporary table or table variable:

```
declare @ratios table (
    DB nvarchar(100),
    TableName nvarchar(100),
    ColumnName nvarchar(100),
    ColumnType nvarchar(20),
    Seed_Value bigint,
    Increment_Value bigint,
    MaxSize bigint,
    Last_value bigint,
    ratio float);

insert into @ratios 
exec sp_MSForEachDB @sql

select * 
from @ratios 
Where ratio>0.001
```

All this can be wrapped into a stored procedure that returns rows that exceed the ratio:

```
create procedure large_identities(@ratio float)
as
declare @sql nvarchar(2000)=N'USE ?; 
select DB_NAME() As DB,
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_ID) as SchemaName,
    object_name(object_id) as TableName,
    name as ColumnName,
    TYPE_NAME(system_type_id) as ColumnType,
    cast(Seed_value as bigint) Seed_Value,
    cast(Increment_value as bigint) as Increment_Value,
    POWER(2.0,max_length*7) as MaxSize,
    cast(last_value as bigint) as Last_value,
    cast(Last_value as bigint)/POWER(2.0,max_length*7) as ratio
from sys.identity_columns;'

declare @ratios table (
    DB nvarchar(100),
    TableName nvarchar(100),
    ColumnName nvarchar(100),
    ColumnType nvarchar(20),
    Seed_Value bigint,
    Increment_Value bigint,
    MaxSize bigint,
    Last_value bigint,
    ratio float);

insert into @ratios 
exec sp_MSForEachDB @sql

select * 
from @ratios 
Where ratio>@ratio
```

And called with the ratio as a parameter:

```
exec large_identities 0.001
```

Comment: Ohh... that looks good. I'll check if this serves my needs. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

SELECT  @SQL = STRING_AGG(CAST(N'
select N' + QUOTENAME(name, N'''') + N' collate database_default AS [catalog]
,   ss.name collate database_default AS [schema]
,   so.name collate database_default as [tablename]
,   s.name collate database_default AS [column]
,   st.name collate database_default AS [type]
,   seed_value, increment_value, s.last_value
,   CASE LOWER(st.name)
            WHEN ''bigint'' THEN CONVERT(BIGINT, last_value) / 9223372036854775807
            WHEN ''int'' THEN CONVERT(INT, last_value) / 2147483647
            WHEN ''smallint'' THEN CONVERT(SMALLINT, last_value) / 32767
            WHEN ''tinyint'' THEN CONVERT(TINYINT, last_value) / 255
        END AS [RATIO]
from ' + QUOTENAME(name) + N'.sys.identity_columns s
inner join ' + QUOTENAME(name) + N'.sys.objects so
    ON  so.object_id = s.object_id
inner join ' + QUOTENAME(name) + N'.sys.types st
    ON  st.user_type_id = s.user_type_id
INNER JOIN  ' + QUOTENAME(name) + N'.sys.schemas ss
    ON  ss.schema_id = so.schema_id
where so.is_ms_shipped = 0
' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), N' UNION ALL ')
FROM    sys.databases
where   state_desc = 'ONLINE'

EXEC    (@SQL)
```

It builds dynamic sql string which unions all databases and executes it once.

I simplified the usage of views so you use something a bit more modern, but you can probably adapt your original script from the general idea.

Comment: `'UNION ALL'` should be at least `' UNION ALL'`. Otherwise each (inner) statement will end with `where so.is_ms_shipped = 0UNION ALL` and a syntax error.

Comment: Actually, it technically works :P But i can change it anyway!

Comment: Huh, it *does*, that feels wrong... Though I did get an error that the value went over 8000 bytes, so I added a `CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),N'')` at the start. This then results in collation errors as I have some different collated databases in my sandbox (so I added some `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT`s).

Comment: Yeah, me too now :P Added some fixes. That's what i get for being fancy, i usually go for ms_foreachdb and a temporary table :)

Comment: `select ' + QUOTENAME(name, '''') + N' collate database_default` is the correct way to escape single quotes `'`. Also would have thought `sys.tables` might be better than `sys.objects`

Comment: There's no need for the JOINs. `OBJECT_NAME` can return the table name given the object_id.  `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME` gives the schema, TYPE_NAME gives the type given a `type_id`. `identity_columns` has a `max_size` field that can be used to calculate the maximum value, removing the need for the CASE

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure those functions work cross databases

Comment: @Charlieface that's pretty neat way of quoting, thanks for the tip! And yeah, sys.tables is probably best, I mostly work with sys.objects so it's a bad habit to always go there

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The system functions can have some issues such as with not respecting isolation level

Comment: As a note as well, `QUOTENAME(name, N'''')` can actually end up with character loss *if* the object name has a character outside of the code page, as it results in `'YourDatabaseName'` (a `varchar`). You can avoid this by putting an `N` inside the literal string directly before the concatenated object name: `N'... N' + QUOTENAME(name, N'''') + N'...'` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R3LSIu2v) (No surprise, I found this one out the hard way).

Comment: @ThomA damn that's a good catch, i'm gonna edit the answer

Comment: That was honestly, *hours* of debugging time, @siggemannen >_<