# Query not completely executed when used in DB job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, sp-send-dbmail

I have the following statement, that when executed directly in an query window sends me the correct result as email

```sql
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'SQL Server Agent Notification',  
    @recipients = '<EMAIL ADDRESS>',  
    @body = 'Please see INT overflow candidates attached',
    @query = '
        declare @sql nvarchar(2000)=N''
        IF ''''?'''' LIKE ''''PROD_%''''
        BEGIN
            USE [?];
            SELECT
                DB_NAME()                                                         AS DB
               ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)                                     AS SchemaName
               ,OBJECT_NAME(object_id)                                            AS TableName
               ,name                                                              AS ColumnName
               ,TYPE_NAME(system_type_id)                                         AS ColumnType
               ,CAST(Seed_Value AS BIGINT)                                        AS Seed_Value
               ,CAST(Increment_Value AS BIGINT)                                   AS Increment_Value
               ,POWER(2.0, (max_length * 8 - 1))                                  AS MaxSize
               ,CAST(Last_value AS BIGINT)                                        AS Last_value
               ,CAST(Last_value AS BIGINT) / POWER(2.0, (max_length * 8 - 1))     AS ratio
            FROM sys.identity_columns
                WHERE TYPE_NAME(system_type_id) = ''''int'''';
        END''

        DECLARE @ratios TABLE (
            DB NVARCHAR(100),
            SchemaName NVARCHAR(29),
            TableName NVARCHAR(100),
            ColumnName NVARCHAR(100),
            ColumnType NVARCHAR(20),
            Seed_Value BIGINT,
            Increment_Value BIGINT,
            MaxSize BIGINT,
            Last_value BIGINT,
            ratio FLOAT);

        INSERT INTO @ratios EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @sql

        SELECT
            *
        FROM @ratios
        WHERE ColumnType = ''int''
            AND DB LIKE ''PROD_%''
            AND ratio >= 0.95',
    @execute_query_database = 'master',
    @subject = 'INT Overflow candidates',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'OverflowCandidates.csv',
    @query_result_header = 1,
    @query_result_width = 512,
    @query_result_separator = ';',
    @exclude_query_output = 1,
    @append_query_error = 1,
    @query_no_truncate = 0,
    @query_result_no_padding = 1;
```

Result:

```
(6546 rows affected)
DB                                                                                                   SchemaName                    TableName                                                                                            ColumnName              
                                                                             ColumnType           Seed_Value           Increment_Value      MaxSize              Last_value           ratio                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------------------
PROD_XXX                                                                                       dbo                           CPM#Balance_BAK_DBA_20220527                                                                         BalanceID               
                                                                             int                                     1                    1           2147483648           2147254332      0.99989321641623974
PROD_XXX                                                                                       dbo                           CPM#Balance_BAK_20220527_SE                                                                          BalanceID               
                                                                             int                                     1                    1           2147483648           2147254332      0.99989321641623974

(2 rows affected)
```

Now I wanted this to be executed on a regular basis (once a week). When I set up the corresponding Server Agent Job I do get an Email, but it seems that the query is not fully executed.

```
(0 rows affected)
DB                                                                                                   SchemaName                    TableName                                                                                            ColumnName              
                                                                             ColumnType           Seed_Value           Increment_Value      MaxSize              Last_value           ratio                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------------------

(0 rows affected)
```

Does someone have any ideas why or how I can solve this?

Comment: probably something with the rights. do you see any errors, and what's the account that runs server agent

Comment: No, there are now errors. I run this task with full rights on the server.

Comment: But does the SQL Server Agent service account have *full rights* on the server? Or (ideally) the permissions to minimally do what it needs to do.

Comment: I'm not sure that's going to actually matter here, @AaronBertrand . The OP uses 3 part naming to execute `sp_send_dbmail` and they also specify `master` for the `@execute_query_database` parameter. The only place they don't specify the database is in their call to `sp_MSforeachdb`; inside the "dynamic" statement they are using `USE [?]` to change db context.

Comment: if you create a job and select suser_name() and then run same script as that user, what happens? execute as ... might be helpful here

Comment: you might wanna avoid sp_msforeachdb, it's buggy and unreliable. i'm pretty sure you were told of a better way of getting data from multiple databases last time you asked this question

Comment: *"i'm pretty sure you were told of a better way"* No idea what you're [talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77006906/2029983), @Siggerman. 

Answer (score 0):

I've now found a solution, but not with the SQL Server Agent.
I've created a Scheduled Task and a Powershell script to execute the query. Now I get the mail with the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Varchars for querys run from Agent are limited in size. So your dynamic code (the parameter @query) is being truncated. Solution: preface your code with SET TEXTSIZE nnnn.
Read more here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/job-truncates-varcharmax-to-512-characters-run-script-from-ssms-does-not

Comment: Hi, I've tried to add the `SET TEXTSIZE` in the `@query` element. Unfortunately it didn't help.